# Hopf-Galois structures of cyclic type on a dihedral or quaternionic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, hopf-algebras

Let $L/K$ be a dihedral or quaternionic finite field extension, that is such that $Gal(L/K)$ is either a dihedral or a quaternion group.
How many Hopf-Galois structures of cyclic type are there on such extension? I am interested, in particular, when Gal(L/K) is isomorphic to either $D_{2^n}$ (or $Q_{2^n}$). I only know that that number is 6 when $Gal(L/K)\cong Q_8$ (source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09497). I have conjectured that, in general, for all such cases, the number I am looking for is $2^{n-2}$.

Comment: Hi Blue! I am quite sure that this question is still open! If you have a look at the appendix of "On skew braces (with an appendix by N. Byott and L. Vendramin)", you will find some tables in which the number of Hopf–Galois structures on finite small extensions is given, for example for small dihedral groups and the quaternion group.